# XML Parser Limits

Tags: asp.net, web-services, xml-parsing, ibm-datapower

So I have an application that sends a request to a web service (performing a search), and I am getting the below exception:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsrr="http://wsrr_standard.[myCompany].com/2.0/"><env:Body><env:Fault><faultcode>200 OK</faultcode><faultstring>DataPower Error Message: document size limit of 4194304 bytes exceeded, aborting</faultstring><detail><errorCode>0x00030003</errorCode><errorNode>XICN0003:6807276</errorNode><errorOrigin>DataPower</errorOrigin><errorLevel>CRITICAL</errorLevel><ConsumerIDfromrequest/><ServiceSubscriberIDfromrequest/><RequestURI>/[MyService].svc</RequestURI><BackendOperation>{http://www.xmlns.[myCompany].com/interfaces/v1_0_2/}[MyMethod]</BackendOperation></detail></env:Fault></env:Body></env:Envelope>'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
```

I was doing some online research regarding the error **DataPower Error Message: document size limit of 4194304 bytes exceeded, aborting** and came across the following page: [XML parser limits exceeded even though the message size is smaller than the XML parser limit set](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21588939) and according to the site one possible solution is to "Disable the probe or increase the XML Parser Limits on the XML Manager attached to the service"

My question is as follows, Can I change t the XML Parser limits in web.config from my service? Or what other possible solution is there?

Comment: This fault is coming from the server. It is the server which has decided that the document size limit has been exceeded.

Comment: Also, why would the limit be specific to ASP.NET?

Comment: so there is no other way but to go to XML Manager and change the settings there?...well, this is a .NET app

Answer (score 0):

There is not other solution. Had to increase the size in the XML Manager in DataPower.